# PHP CKeditor sends empty data on $_POST to the database by using ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms, ckeditor

the `CKEditor` is loaded correctly. but when I Want to insert data to the database it sends empty data.
this is the `form` I have used for sending data.

```
<form action="ajax/EditDeleteLecture.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form1">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Choose file: </label>
    <input type="file" name="files" id="files" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" style="border:1px solid #464C6B">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Date" class="control-label">Description</label>
    <textarea id="editor1" name="editor1"  class="form-control" tabindex="2" rows="10" cols="80">
    </textarea>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <span id='message'></span>
    <div class="col-md-12">                                         
    <span id="success_message" class="text-success"></span>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" data-dismiss="modal" onclick='addRecord()'>Upload</button>
    </div>    
    </div>
</form>
```

And this `function AddRecord()` wilsendds the data to `EditDeleteNewsAndEvents.php` page for Insertion.

```
function addRecord(){
     var formData = new FormData($("#form1")[0]); //It automatically collects all fields from form
            $.ajax({
                url: "ajax/EditDeleteNewsAndEvents.php",
                type: "post",
                data: formData,
                 async: false,
                 cache: false,
                 contentType: false,
                 processData: false,
             success: function(output) {
                alertify.set('notifier','delay', 3);
                alertify.set('notifier','position', 'top-right');
                alertify.success('Data Inserted Successfully');            
                 readRecords();
                 $('#form1').trigger("reset");
                }

    });
}
```

And this code I have written in the `EditDeleteNewsAndEvents.php` page to insert the data into the database. but when i receive this `$desc = $_POST['editor1'];` this variable it shows empty in the `Network Pane`.

```
//adding records in database
if(isset($_FILES['files']['name']))
{
    $files = $_FILES['files']['name']; 
    $desc = $_POST['editor1'];
    $path='News_And_Events_Images/'.$files;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"], $path);
    $date =  date('d-M-y');

          echo $query = "INSERT INTO news_events(body,posted_by,posted_date,pic) VALUES ('$desc','$single_user','$date','$path')"; exit;

         $cm=sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);
}
```

And This is shown in the `Network Pane`.

```
INSERT INTO news_events(body,posted_by,posted_date,pic) VALUES ('                                            ','0302254855','06-Nov-18','News_And_Events_Images/0bd5583c05354dbceb79c833c27f6c68.jpg')
```

Comment: As an aside, `async: false` is deprecated and should not be used. Most browsers will now issue a warning about it. It can create a bad user experience by locking the browser UI while the ajax request is running - if it takes longer than expected, users may think the browser has crashed. You should have no practical need for it, in any case, your code is correctly written to handle an asynchronous request.

Comment: A second aside: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php) for examples of how to write your queries safely using parameters. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: Regarding your issue, can you please show us the code where you set up your CKEditor. You claim it's "set up correctly", but your issue indicates that probably it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a specific variable for the CKEDITOR in your `function addRecord()`:

```
 var ckInfo = CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData();
```

In my case, it works fine, but then you should change a little bit your `data` variable.

Comment: so how can I send it to EditDeleteNewsAndEvents.php Page??

Comment: In your case, maybe you could get all data from form except textarea. Then, your `data` variable Ajax would look like this: `data: {formData, ckInfo}` Take a look to the documentation [here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/saving-data.html), it can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

When you are sending data to server using traditional forms, then `textarea` is being [updated with editor content automatically](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-autoUpdateElement). This is because the data is being taken from the `textarea` and not the editor which is not a form element like `textarea` is.

If however you are using AJAX to send your request, you should either update the [textarea manually](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#method-updateElement) and then get data from it or you should [get data from the editor directly](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#method-getData).